# Trying to merge dataFrame

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

Please have a look at the picture. [image]

I've been trying to solve this problem on my own, but unfortunately I haven't been successful.
I basically want to have the following format:

```
     close1        close2
date   x              x
       x              x

***code***

import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import pandas as pd
from pandas import Series, DataFrame
import ystockquote

#eon
his1 = ystockquote.get_historical_prices('EOAN.DE', '2013-01-01', '2013-01-10')
eon = DataFrame(his1)

close_eon = eon.ix["Close"]

#RWE
his2 = ystockquote.get_historical_prices('RWE.DE', '2013-01-01', '2013-01-10')
rwe = DataFrame(his2)


close_rwe = rwe.ix["Close"]

fig = plt.figure(); ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax.plot(close_eon)
ax.plot(close_rwe)
plt.show()

eonrwe = eon.append(rwe)
```

Comment: how about copying and pasting the code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you concatenate the `close` series?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import pandas.io.data as web


start = pd.datetime(2013, 1, 1)
end = pd.datetime(2013, 1, 10)

eon = web.DataReader("EOAN.DE", 'yahoo', start, end)
rwe = web.DataReader("RWE.DE", 'yahoo', start, end)
closes = pd.concat({ "eon" : eon["Close"], "rwe" : rwe["Close"]}, axis=1)
closes.plot()
```

Gives

```
             eon     rwe
2013-01-01   14.09   31.24
2013-01-02   14.35   31.61
2013-01-03   14.40   31.53
2013-01-04   14.51   31.90
2013-01-07   14.26   30.93
2013-01-08   14.22   30.95
2013-01-09   14.40   31.30
2013-01-10   14.35   30.70
```

[image]

Comment: Hey, @aaaa, I updated my answer to use pandas built-in Yahoo Finance scraper. It removes a dependency, makes label handling in the concatenation easier, and automatically handles the datetime issue I had to manually deal with previously. If you're not wedded to `ystockquote` I highly recommend it!